# Modify style shadowroot element through css

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have CustomField with FormLayout inside and i want change #layout element of FormLayout inside #shadow-root. Of course, i can do that by js:

```js
document.querySelector("#myid > vaadin-form-layout")
.shadowRoot
.querySelector("#layout").style.<property>=hz;
```

Is it possible to change the style of an element using css?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the styling documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/getting-started/#styling.get-started.shadow-dom-styling

But do note, that the `#layout` element is considered an internal implementation detail, and it is not guaranteed to be available in future releases (major, minor, or maintenance). The element might be gone or the ID change at any point.